# Automatically open hyperlink in currently selected row

Tags: excel, database, hyperlink, tags

I'm attempting to categorize, tag, and database a collection of over six terabytes of video clips and game recordings from my extensive playtime in Battlefield 4, and in an attempt to make that as efficient as possible, I've inserted hyperlinks to the files on my hard drive into the spreadsheet, such that I can single click, and the video will begin playing in VLC.

However, as I've got over 10,000 files to tag and work through (I know, it's kind of absurd), I wanted to improve the process a bit by making the spreadsheet automatically "click" the hyperlink once I advanced to the next row.

I've got a number of columns for common categories that I'll probably use, and essentially I want to enter the series of tags for the given video file, hit enter, and the next video file in the list will begin playing in VLC, without me even switching windows, clicking, or anything.

I'm pretty new to Excel, but this project is essentially a way for me to learn and grow in my knowledge.

Bonus question: is there a better way for doing filter-as-you-type than the various tutorials such as this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCahRfEGj1g?

This method is unfortunately not efficient for large lists, so I'm hoping there's a better way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand... is sounds like you just want to make an playlist that lets you search by tags and auto-plays the next file (just like a VLC playlist already does).  What's the end-goal?

Comment: @ashleedawg, I'm looking to make a list of the video clips I've accumulated, and have relevant tags associated and searchable, so that I'm able to find the exact clip I'm looking for by narrowing the list down via tags.